# Unit test hangs in Android while testing suspend function

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I have a suspend function in a repository layer of my application. I'm trying to unit test the function but every time it executes it seems to hang on the `await()` invocation and then just stays there forever and never finishes. It looks like there's some deadlock going on in the background but it isn't immediately apparent what's going on.

Does anyone have any solutions here?

Here's my repo function:

```
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): DataState<AuthViewState> {
        try {
            val authResult = firebaseAuth
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .await()

            return DataState.data<AuthViewState>(
                data = AuthViewState(
                    authResult.user?.uid
                )
            )
        } catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "loginUserIfExisting: FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: ", e)
            return DataState.error<AuthViewState>(
                "User not found. Please register."
            )
        } catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "loginUserIfExisting: FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: ", e)
            return DataState.error<AuthViewState>(
                "Your password/email is incorrect. Please try again."
            )
        }
    }
```

And here's my test with mocks:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class AuthRepositoryTest {

    private val email = "lee.a.wilson90@gmail.com"
    private val password = "fakepassword"
    private val CORRECT_USER_ID = "CORRECT_USER_ID"

    private lateinit var SUT: AuthRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    @Mock
    private lateinit var authResultTask: Task<AuthResult>

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockResult: AuthResult

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockFirebaseUser: FirebaseUser

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockUserPropertiesDao: UserPropertiesDao

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockSharedPreferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        `when`(firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
            .thenReturn(authResultTask)

        `when`(mockResult.user)
            .thenReturn(mockFirebaseUser)

        `when`(mockFirebaseUser.uid)
            .thenReturn("CORRECT_USER_ID")

        `when`(mockUserPropertiesDao.searchByEmail(email))
            .thenReturn(null)

        `when`(mockSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.PREVIOUS_AUTH_USER, null))
            .thenReturn(null)

        SUT = AuthRepository(
            firebaseAuth,
            mockUserPropertiesDao,
            mockSharedPreferences,
            mockSharedPreferencesEditor
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun test_correctCredentialsEntered_correctOutputState() = runBlocking {
        whenever(authResultTask.await()).thenReturn(mockResult)
        val resultState = SUT.login(email, password)
        val result = resultState.data!!.getContentIfNotHandled()!!.uid
        assertEquals(CORRECT_USER_ID, result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `runBlockingTest` instead of `runBlocking`?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately the test fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet`. Different behaviour, but I don't really understand why the `await()` function doesn't return immediately in my test setup.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong with test setup, read here if you didn't: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito doesn't seem to support suspend functions yet.

So instead of mocking `authResultTask: Task<AuthResult>` (which I think was a bad idea anyway), you should use a [`TaskCompletionSource<AuthResult>`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource) and set the result of it.

EDIT:

To complete this answer by giving an explanation to the observed behaviour.

The unit test hangs because `Continuation<T>.resume()` isn't called by mockito when you mock the `await()` function.